# VBA to create formula based on another variable

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to create the formula below using vba in excel

```
=SUM(COUNTIF(E7,"Vac")+ COUNTIF(E7,"LWOP")+COUNTIF(R7,"Vac")+ COUNTIF(R7,"LWOP"))
```

But E7 and R7 will change based on another variable called `rCell.address`

Below is the code that I have within the macro and it is giving an error:

```
Range("a8").Formula = "=SUMIF(countif(" & rCell.Address & ", "VAC"" & "))"
```

The current macro is:

```
Sub Find()

Dim strdate As String
Dim rCell As Range
Dim lReply As Long

With Worksheets("Sheet1")
strdate = .Range("a1").Value
End With

If strdate = "False" Then Exit Sub
strdate = Format(strdate, "Short Date")

On Error Resume Next

    Set rCell = Cells.Find(What:=CDate(strdate), After:=Range("A1"), LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)

On Error GoTo 0

If rCell Is Nothing Then
    lReply = MsgBox("Date cannot be found. Try Again", vbYesNo)
    If lReply = vbYes Then Run "FindDate":
End If

Range("a8").Formula = "=SUMIF(countif(" & rCell.Address & ",VAC" & "))"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am assuming that your error appears on this line of code: `Range("a8").Formula = "=SUMIF(countif(" & rCell.Address & ",VAC" & "))"`.

You should change that line to

```
Range("a8").Formula = "=SUM(COUNTIF(" & rCell.Address & "," & Chr(34) & "Vac" & Chr(34) & ")+ COUNTIF(" & rCell.Address & "," & Chr(34) & "LWOP" & Chr(34) & ")+COUNTIF(" & rCell.Offset(0, 13).Address & "," & Chr(34) & "Vac" & Chr(34) & ")+ COUNTIF(" & rCell.Offset(0, 13).Address & "," & Chr(34) & "LWOP" & Chr(34) & "))"
```

**Updated with better answer thanks to KS Sheon**

```
Range("a8").Formula = "=SUM(COUNTIF(" & rCell.Address & ",""Vac"")+ COUNTIF(" & rCell.Address & ",""LWOP"")+COUNTIF(" & rCell.Offset(0, 13).Address & ",""Vac"")+ COUNTIF(" & rCell.Offset(0, 13).Address & ",""LWOP""))"
```

Comment: alternative for Chr(34) is double quote (""). it'd be like `"=sum(countif(" & [a1].Address & ", ""VAC""))"
`

Comment: Ah, thank you! Much appreciated @KSSheon; I've updated my answer with the more compact code.

Comment: Thank You so much Nick. It is working how it is supposed to be. Sorry for the late reply.

Comment: @user3323922 Awesome, glad it helped!

Answer (score 1):

`SUMIF` is wrong in this context.

```
Range("a8").Formula = "=SUMIF(countif(" & rCell.Address & ",VAC" & "))"
```

you should use `SUMIF` like this

```
Range("a8").Formula =SUMIF(B2:B25,">5")
```